# How to use multiple Nodelists with forEach method

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, foreach

I'm working on a project that is basically a e-store, with a bin. What I'm trying to do is send a POST request to the server with my items from the bin.
I have an empty array. I also have 3 Nodelists, I want to reach their values, textContent, dataset and nest all of them in my empty array.
This is the array:

`var products = { Lines: [ ] };`

What I've tried so far:

```
const prName = this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.product-name-link');
const prInput = this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.product-quantity-input');
const prPrice = this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.product-price-total');

prName.forEach(product => products.push(product.dataset.id))
prInput.forEach(product => products.Lines.push(product.value))
prPrice.forEach(product => products.Lines.push(product.textContent))
```

I want them to have a key=> value like in the example above.

The result that I need to get looks similar to this:

```
"Lines":[
    {
     "Assortiment":"1627aea5-8e0a-4371-9022-9b504344e724",
     "Quantity":12678967.543233,
     "SalePrice":12678967.543233,
     "Warehouse":"1627aea5-8e0a-4371-9022-9b504344e724"
    },
    {
     "Assortiment":"1627aea5-8e0a-4371-9022-9b504344e724",
     "Quantity":12678967.543233,
     "SalePrice":12678967.543233,
     "Warehouse":"1627aea5-8e0a-4371-9022-9b504344e724"
    },
    {
     "Assortiment":"1627aea5-8e0a-4371-9022-9b504344e724",
     "Quantity":12678967.543233,
     "SalePrice":12678967.543233,
     "Warehouse":"1627aea5-8e0a-4371-9022-9b504344e724"
    }
    ],
```

Comment: Where and how did your approach fail? Be more precise with what the actual input is, e.g. the data that you want to collect from what kind of DOM structure.

Comment: The input is a quantity input. The data that I collect is the ID of the product. It's a regular cart of products, the products that I've selected I want to save them into the empty array that I've created above so I could use it further in a POST Request, where I send the data collected. The data collected must have the structure of the result example I've written above.

Comment: so in order to be consistent in first place, the fourth line of the example code should state something like this too ... `products.Lines.push(product.dataset.id))` ..? (yes, I'm aware of this is not the solution yet)

Comment: btw. without knowing the DOM structure, everything the community will provide you is just guessing. And if your approach actually is ... querying everything and then hoping that the assumption of "each same index in each of the 3 different node-lists does always target the same dataset" does always pay off ... then my gut feeling does not really like it.

Comment: Yeah, that was just a mistake. `roducts.Lines.push(product.dataset.id)`  is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... with everything already said in my comments, a working solution might look like that ...

```
const products = { Lines: [] };

const prName = this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.product-name-link');
const prInput = this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.product-quantity-input');
const prPrice = this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.product-price-total');

// create a product item with each iteration step ...
prName.forEach((elmNode, idx) => products.Lines.push({
  Assortiment: elmNode.dataset.id,
  Quantity: prInput.item(idx).value,
  SalePrice: prPrice.item(idx).textContent
}));
```

Comment: It works, thank you! What is item(idx) in this case? Would you explain?

Comment: `item` is a `NodeList`'s accessor method. Of course using the `[]` operator does work on arrays and node lists alike. Thus `prInput[idx].value` and `prPrice[idx].textContent` is the more common syntax for accessing the node-list items from  your example.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap them with `Array.from()` as follows:

```
Array.from(elements).forEach( function(el) {
    console.log(el);
});
```

Comment: I doubt that to be the answer, the OP is looking for. 1st, the example makes use of the query syntax, thus there are `NodeList`s one already can iterate with `forEach`, `keys`, `values` and `entries` ... there is no need for `Array.from`. 2nd, the OP's problem seems to be more of how to structure/aggregate data,; but unfortunately the way how it is explained or ask for is not that precise.

Comment: I agree that the explanation isn't quite precise. I want my querySelectors to be structured in the empty array, just like in the last piece of code, except not having the `Warehouse` line.

Comment: @PeterSeliger yep i couldn't understand the question properly so i thought maybe this is the answer. happy to edit if the OP provides details.

Comment: @PeterSeliger it's because the question isn't properly explained. i always hear the hate on SO but if you actually take the time to ask a question properly, you almost always get an answer. look at my profile for example. there are very few (<5) occassions when i didn't get an answer. sometimes people just don't even put an effort to ask properly like OP. hence, the downvote. we can't help you if you can't help us understand your question properly.